# how to stop endless redirect after successful login

Tags: grails, redirect, spring-security

My grails app is using Spring Security (Acegi). Users can login on `/login`. after this is successful it redirects to `/`. if someone now tries get back to the URL `/login` the browser says "endless redirect, the request could never be ended". in the `login` controller, action `login` which shows the login view there is some code

```
if (isLoggedIn()) {
  redirect uri: '/'
  return
}
```

but this (and the whole action) is not executed when one hit `/login` and is loggedin.

SecurityConfig declares

```
/login/**=ROLE_ANONYMOUS
```

Any tipps how I stopp the redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want ROLE_ANONYMOUS since authenticated users won't have it, it's just a fake role that nonauthenticated users get. Use IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY instead. This means nonauthenticated, authenticated via remember-me cookie, or authenticated via login form (i.e. all users).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! That works fine. I thought that roles are hierarchily organized? ROLE_ANONYMOUS < ROLE_USER

Comment: There's support for hierarchical roles but you have to define the hierarchy - see section 10.12 in [the docs](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/)